# Charset change after POST Request

Tags: php, unicode, character-encoding

I'm using a meta tag on my page for setting the encoding for the page:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Everything works fine if it's a GET Request, but when I submit a form (like a search form) and do a POST Request, all of the unicode characters convert to weird letters.

Why this is happening?

Comment: What do the requests look like? What is your code for setting the encoding/writing the response? What are the "weird letters"?

Comment: Made a few adjustments to your wording and capitalization, but most importantly I used the code formatting tags so that your meta tag didn't get absorbed into unrendered HTML code. :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solution i very simple. Put `<body>` `</body>` and this will solve the problem.